# The place to store image (blob) on an iPad?

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsuserdefaults

I thought about using `NSUserDefaults` to store a single image, but i know this is discouraged.

Now, I tried using the new Asset library mechanism, but I failed to get it to work.
I tried this because my original idea of storing/retrieving the image URL (path on local disk) is not supported (Apple did away with this for some reason).

So now I'm here asking for ideas on where/how to store information so that I can load a pre-selected image. And note that I am already using Core Data (a single entity type) to populate a tableview. I suppose I could create a 2nd entity type just for this. Is this the recommendation, or is there still yet a simpler or more clever way?

Ex: User "favorites" a specific image. The next time the app loads I'd like to display that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the app's document directory:

```
+ (NSString *) applicationDocumentsDirectory 
{    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

Note that this directory is erased when the user removes the app.

Comment: Thanks. Let me give this a try!

Comment: btw, will this be able to store the image path? I guess more importantly, will I be able to create a UIImage based on a saved image PATH alone?

Comment: Sure, you can store the image path wherever you want, and you can create a UIImage from the object saved in that path